# Can emails be sent in bulk to progress a sales cadence?

Tags: email, sales

Say a user has added 5 contacts to a cadence assigned to themself and the first step in the cadence is to send a manual email. Normally, they would open their work queue and click the email icon to send an email to each contact individually.

Is there a way to send a list email/mass email to all contacts in a given user's work queue AND have this list email progress the contacts to the next step in the sales cadence? Can I maybe customize the work queue to allow bulk email deliverability?

I tested creating a list view filtered on the user's sales cadence contacts and sending a list email, but it did not progress the sales cadence step for the contacts. I did this in a sandbox and noticed that SF says the emails were delivered, but the contacts did not receive the email. I have already confirmed my deliverability settings are accurate and sending a single manual email works as expected.

Comment: Have you tried the email step in the cadence builder? https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_sales_hvs_automated_emails.htm&type=5&release=224

Comment: @identigral I have, but we want to be able to review the Lead/Contact details before sending emails out to confirm there arent any issues with the fields that are going to be added to email templates as merge fields. For that reason, the email step we are using is Manual.

Comment: There's no way to do this out of the box, it would be a sizeable customization. There are some ideas in https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdhBIUAZ/send-an-email-queue-emails-for-reviewapproval-before-sending on how to solve a similar issue. Whatever you do you'd have to marry it with the workflow in cadence. Defeats the purpose of cadence automation feature.